# How do I set the path from user input for a new process using ProcessBulder?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I want to add new process using `ProcessBulder` class in Java. But process name is taken from user input then how to set the path?

The user only enter the process name like `firefox.exe`, but it does not start directly, it throws `PathNotFoundException`. How can I identify the path of user's input? Or how should I start the process which entered by the user?

Comment: Plz add your code thats not working and the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be either full path or the program should be in a folder known to OS via PATH variable, or the program should be in working dir